# Export a Datagrid WPF C# to excel

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

I am new with C#,
I spent time to looking for the answer to the question about how export a datagrid WPF developed in C# to excel. I find some solutions like use CSV files, but this solution does not allow create sheets in excel, or change a format cell.

Finally I find a solution that iterate cell by cell from the datagrid from this link: [how to loop through all the the cells in datagrid](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/290d3c67-440e-4037-86b6-cf668990b5da/how-to-loop-through-all-the-the-cells-in-datagrid?forum=wpf) and then I use the library to export to excel  Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.

The code that I am using is the following:

```
private void export_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        excel.Visible = true;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook workbook = excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value);
        DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

        for (int h = 0; h < _headers.Count; h++)
        {
            int fila = 1;
            dg = ownername_to_datagrid[_headersown[h]];
            workbook.Sheets.Add(After: workbook.Sheets[workbook.Sheets.Count]); // Adiciona una nueva hoja de calculo
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet RCSA1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[h + 1];
            RCSA1.Name = _headers[h];
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)RCSA1.Cells[fila, 1];
            for (int j = 0; j < dg.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)RCSA1.Cells[fila, j + 1];
                RCSA1.Cells[fila, j + 1].Font.Bold = true;
                RCSA1.Columns[j + 1].ColumnWidth = 15;
                myRange.Value2 = dg.Columns[j].Header;
            }
            fila++;

            for (int i = 0; i < dg.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < dg.Columns.Count; j++)
                {
                    DataGridCell cell = GetCell(i, j, dg);
                    if (cell == null)
                    {

                        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
                        tb.Text = "x";
                        myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)RCSA1.Cells[fila, j + 1];
                        myRange.Value2 = tb.Text;
                        //MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TextBlock tb = cell.Content as TextBlock;
                        myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)RCSA1.Cells[fila, j + 1];
                        myRange.Value2 = tb.Text;
                        //MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);
                    }
                }
                fila++;
            }
        }
        MessageBox.Show("Finalizado el proceso de exportación");
    }

    public DataGridCell GetCell(int row, int column, DataGrid dg)
    {
        DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(row, dg);

        if (rowContainer != null)
        {
            DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>(rowContainer);

            DataGridCell cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            if (cell == null)
            {
                dg.ScrollIntoView(rowContainer, dg.Columns[column]);
                cell = (DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(column);
            }
            return cell;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public DataGridRow GetRow(int index, DataGrid dg)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        if (row == null)
        {
            dg.UpdateLayout();
            dg.ScrollIntoView(dg.Items[index]);
            row = (DataGridRow)dg.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index);
        }
        return row;
    }

    public static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

Explaining the code, the first for loop is to generate 2 sheets with the correspond name, each sheet conatins a datagrid, then the frist for loop inside of the for is to export to excel the header (title) of each column, then the next for is to print the content of each datagrid cell to excel.

The Problems that I have are the following:
If I dont refresh each tab that contain the datagrid (I know that the datagrid has data but I don't open the tab) when I export to excel I detect null values. (I put a conditional that print x when detect null values)

My screen in c# looks like:
[image: C# tabs to excel]

I didn't open the RCSA tab that contains a datagrid with data, when I see the excel, it has the following:
[image: RCSA TAB Null Values]

Finnally sometimes, with the same data, appears the following error:
[image: error].

To avoid this errors I just have to open the RCSA tab and make click inside of the datagrid, or just view the whole datagrid.

I don't know what is happening, or why is neede like refresh the datagrid in the C# view,

Thank you for your help

Comment: you are not refreshing the grid, but since there is no request to create is visual element, when you try to access it, it throws null exception, grid object needs to be initialized before you  can access it

Comment: The only way to refresh the grid is visualizing the datagrid tab by tab? or there is some spcial comand to refresh it?

Comment: well as per basics of wpf, you can access the data from the bound object